# Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have this class which allow to send update request to the database through Dapper in Serializable transaction:

```
    public async Task<int> UpdateTable(UpdateModel model)
    {
        await using var connection = createConnection();
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        await using var tx = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
        var rowsCount = await connection.ExecuteAsync(@$"

            UPDATE Table WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
            SET
                Date = @Date,
                Attempts = Attempts + 1
            WHERE
                Id = @Id
                AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Date, GETDATE()) < 60",
            new
            {
                model.Id,
                model.Date
            }, commandTimeout: connection.CommandTimeout, transaction: tx);
        tx.Commit();
        return rowsCount;
    }
```

I send 10 requests async and print result like this:

```
var count = 10;

while (true)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var providerId = Guid.NewGuid();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        tasks.Add(upsert(providerId));

    var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

    result.Wait();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
}

async Task upsert(Guid id)
{
    var response = await client.Upsert(new UpsertModel
    {
        Id = id,
        Date = DateTime.Now
    });

    Console.WriteLine($"RowsCount: {response.Content}, Id: {id}");
}
```

When I sent 10 async requests I receive deadlocks for 9 request from 10. The message looks look like this:
Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock resources with anot
her process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Why I recieve deadlocks? And what I need to do that I can avoid deadlock?

Comment: Remove the `WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)` and have an index on `Id, Date`.

Comment: @GSerg But if I need queue for updating on of records what I need to do? I mean if sql recieve 2 async requests simultaneously, I need that one of them waiting while the first will end and then the second will start. Can I do it without deadlocks?

Comment: Async is not relevant. "SQL" is [not a database](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/11683). You can never eliminate deadlocks, you can only make them less frequent. You should not get in the way of your (unspecified) database when it tries to do its work. In your specific situation, there is no need to either make the transaction serializable or to use the hint.

Comment: @Russo please specify if you are using [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info), [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle), or any other SQL database. If you can tell the version, the better.

Answer (score 1):

In my answer, I will assume you are using SQL Server, since `UPDLOCK` is a SQL Server specific keyword.

Let's refer to [the table hints docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16)

There is a big red warning:

> Attention
>
> Because the SQL Server Query Optimizer typically selects the best execution plan for a query, we recommend that **hints be used only as a last resort** by experienced developers and database administrators.

`UPDLOCK` will put an exclusive lock the whole table if it has any good reason to do so. Since you build your query to update different rows, you may use the `ROWLOCK` hint, provided you do not update ten of thousands of rows with a single UPDATE instruction.

The simpler way to deal with your problem, is, as the Micorsoft page puts it, **to not use table hints.**